# Average sum for each user grouped by month

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables 1) Users(userId, age) 2) Purchases (purchaseId, userId, itemId, date) 3) Items (itemId, price). Goal is to write a query to show average sum of purchase for each user grouped by month. I'm currently not sure if I even need the first table, so far I have smth like this:

```
SELECT Purchases.userid, Purchases.date, Purchases.itemId Items.itemId, AVG(SUM(Items.price))
FROM Purchases
INNER JOIN Purchases.itemId ON Items.itemId
GROUP BY (somehow group by month)
```

And I'm stuck. Could you please explain, how to write such a query. Sorry that I don't have examples of tables, or correct output example, since it is a test task. Thanks!

Comment: add sample data and expected output?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As I mentioned: " Sorry that I don't have examples of tables, or correct output example, since it is a test task."

Comment: **"somehow group by month"** is solved by using a function on the date column, but as you have not identified which database you use (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, Postgres) we cannot suggest which function to use. Each database differs in function names but each has a function to return year and month from any date. (So choose a tag that tells us which database you actually need this for.)

Comment: @ Used_By_Already Database is not specified. It is a test task, so, I presume, I can use any dialect.

Comment: So, choose one & use that as a tag. (ps: no space between @ and username)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use double aggregate like `AVG(SUM(Items.price))`

So you might be a subquery to get `SUM` then use `AVG`

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    Purchases.userid, 
    YEAR(Purchases.date), 
    MONTH(Purchases.date), 
    Purchases.itemId 
    Items.itemId, 
    AVG(Items.SumPrice)
FROM
    Purchases 
INNER JOIN
    Users T2 ON Purchases.userId = T2.userId
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         itemId, SUM(price) AS SumPrice
     FROM  
         Items
     GROUP BY 
         itemId) AS Items ON Items.itemId
GROUP BY  
    Purchases.userid, Purchases.itemId, 
    YEAR(Purchases.date), 
    MONTH(Purchases.date),
    Items.itemId
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT p.userid, itm.itemId, YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date), AVG(itm.price)
FROM Purchases p
INNER JOIN Items itm ON p.itemId = itm.itemId
GROUP BY p.userid, itm.itemId, YEAR(p.date), MONTH(p.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT Purchases.userid, MONTH(Purchases.date), AVG(Items.price)
FROM Purchases
INNER JOIN Items ON  Purchases.itemId = Items.itemId
GROUP BY Purchases.userid, MONTH(Purchases.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by month requires placing a date into "buckets" for the year and month related to that date. Each database type has it's own unique set of functions for this, e.g.

```
--MS SQL Server
SELECT Purchases.userid, Purchases.itemId, year(Purchases.date), month(Purchases.date), AVG(Items.price)
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY Purchases.userid, Purchases.itemId, year(Purchases.date), month(Purchases.date)

--Oracle
SELECT Purchases.userid, Purchases.itemId, trunc(Purchases.date,'YYYYMM'), AVG(Items.price)
FROM Purchases
GROUP BY Purchases.userid, Purchases.itemId, trunc(Purchases.date,'YYYYMM')
```